# Undefined symbol in static lib linked into dynamic library

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, static-libraries, undefined-symbol

here is my issue:

At runtime my program which load shared library fail to load one, it says:

```
libCommunicationModule.so: undefined symbol __builtin_delete
```

the context:

- compiler: gcc 3.4
- Linux Debian 4.0 (old stuff ....)

I have a static library: **libtgi_cppd.a** , I don't have the source of this library.
This lib is linked into the shared library **libCommunicationModule.so** with these options
`-Wl,-whole-archive -ltgi_cppd`

I enabled `-y` option on `__builtin_delete` to check:

```
libtgi_cppd.a(ClientAPI_cpp.o): reference to __builtin_delete
libtgi_cppd.a(ClientInterface.o): reference to __builtin_delete
libtgi_cppd.a(ClientAPI_cpp.o): reference to __builtin_delete
```

I try to add to link command `-lstdc++ -lgcc` before and after `-whole-archive`, no change.

```
$ nm libCommunicationModule.so | grep __builtin
```

result is always like this:

```
     U __builtin_delete
     U __builtin_new
     U __builtin_vec_new
```

What can I do to solve this issue?

Thank you

Full command as requiered:

```
g++ -Wl,-y -Wl,__builtin_delete -Wl,--trace -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/qt/lib -shared 
-Wl,-soname,libCommunicationModule-x11-Debug.so.6 -Wl,-rpath,/home/sncf/AGC_IHM/AGC/Tms/Gui/Components/CommunicationModule/x11/Debug 
-o libCommunicationModule-x11-Debug.so.6.0.1 x11/Debug/Obj/CommunicationModule-Build.o x11/Debug/Obj/CommunicationModuleFilesAutoGen.o x11/Debug/Obj/CommunicationModuleParamsAutoGen.o 
x11/Debug/Obj/CommunicationModule.o 
x11/Debug/Obj/CommunicationModuleAutoGen.o 
x11/Debug/Obj/CommDebugDlg.o 
x11/Debug/Obj/moc_CommunicationModule.o x11/Debug/Obj/moc_CommDebugDlg.o  
-L/usr/local/qt/lib 
-L/usr/X11R6/lib -lBuildInformations-x11-Debug 
-lBagsLib-x11-Debug -lConfigParamsLib-x11-Debug 
-lIniLib-x11-Debug -lModuleHandling-x11-Debug 
-lGenericRuntimeInfoLib-x11-Debug 
-lDebugLib-x11-Debug -lTCNLib-x11-Debug 
-lGUITools-x11-Debug -lQtEventsLib-x11-Debug 
-lPackUnpack-x11-Debug -L/home/sncf/AGC_IHM/AGC/Tms/Gui/ProjectLib/x11 
-L/home/sncf/AGC_IHM/AGC/Tms/Gui/Components/AGCTCNClientAPI/2004.09.21/posix_linux_i586/lib
-lqt-mt -lXext -lX11 -lm -lpthread -Wl,-whole-archive -ltgi_cppd -lstdc++ -lgcc
```

Comment: I just check with ldd, everything is fine, it accesses both system libs and specific application libs, and permissions are fine.

Comment: @dgrat looking at nm result, I saw the static lib was gcc2_compiled (so surely 2.95). I check what can be done for compatibility.

Comment: Show your link command and all other relevant commands as is in their entirety, with all options and arguments and flags unedited verbatim, and please make extra sure you reproduce them from start to end without omitting anything in between.

Comment: @n-m Add the linker command. Then the application load the shared library like a plugin, that where my undefined symbols occurs.

Comment: -lstdc++ -lgcc were when I was running out of idea :) . I check you link as soon as I can, my company proxy is currently blocking it. Thank for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You linked against a library which was compiled/linked by another compiler/linker version. What you need is to link against a library which was compiled and linked by the same compiler/linker as used by yourself, or you have to make sure, that the libraries are at least binary compatible.

Comment: You just saved my day by making me realise my problem (similar to OP's) was caused by trying to call C++ function from C without specifying `extern C` in C++ code. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

1. Execute command ldd  and it will list out all shared libraries using by your program.
2. Check the environment variable LIBPATH /LD_PATH in your execution environment. And make sure all those libraries are present in that path
3. Make sure all library files have sufficient  permission